# Attribute error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'employee_id'

Tags: sql

If you write column numbers manually, everything works.

```
items.append({'employee_id':row[0],'last_name':row[2]})
```

How can I do this via KEY_VALUES?

Would like to do this using KEY-VALUES

```
for row in result:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['employee_id'] = row.employee_id
    d['last_name'] = row.last_name
    items.append(d)
```

I get this error

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'employee_id'

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL.  You should tag with the tool that you are using.  I might speculate Python, but that would be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

`row` doesn't have `employee_id` and `last_name` attributes, just positional members:

```py
for row in result:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['employee_id'] = row[0] # Here
    d['last_name'] = row[2] # And here
    items.append(d)
```

Comment: If I add a row, is the integrity preserved, or do I need to edit the column numbers??

Comment: @Абыл each row has the same indexes (i.e, each row's index 0 is the employee id)